# $x^3+nx+2$ is irreducible over ${\mathbb Z}$ for $n\neq 1,\ -3\ -5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that $$x^3+nx +2 $$ is irreducible over ${\bf Z}$ for $n\neq 1,\ -3\ -5$

By Eisenstein, if $n$ is even then it is irreducible. How can we solve odd case ?

[add] Note that factorization is one of these : 
 $$ (x\pm 2)(x^2+ax\pm 1),\ (x\pm 1)(x^2+ax\pm 2) $$

Since $x^2$-term do not exist we can determine $a$. So $n$

Comment: Since this is a cubic it has at most three real roots.  You should look at the formula (or methods for solving) cubics and see what you can say about $n$ when you apply them.

Comment: Hint: Any integer root must be one of $\pm 1,\pm 2$.

Comment: I will add solution from helps.

Comment: Compute $f(x)$ for $x=-2,-1,1,2$.